# nrwl nx React tutorial confusing

Tags: nrwl-nx

Following the [Getting Started](https://nx.dev/react/getting-started/getting-started) docs for nrwl react and the tutorial.  The docs have you run specific commands and then show the folder structure that should be created.  I am not seeing the same folder structure.  (and some additional issues).

running `nx g @nrwl/react:lib --project=ui` should result in the following structure according to image shown:

`workspace/libs/ui/src/lib/ui/(ui.css, ui.spec.tsx, ui.tsx)`

instead I am getting:

`workspace/libs/ui/src/lib/(files, etc.)`

no second UI folder.  Additionally, the docs show how to add components with `nx g @nrwl/react:component todos --project=ui`.  When done I should have the following structure:

`workspace/libs/ui/src/lib/todos/(todo files)`

again, instead I get a structure:

`workspace/libs/ui/src/lib/(todo files)`

no todos folder.  It is simply placing all component files into a single directory `workspace/libs/ui/src/lib/`

I am aware that the generate command can take a `--directory` parameter and this results in what is expected.  So I'm mainly wondering if I might be doing something wrong or that the docs are just out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start with empty workspace and than add react or angular capability into that.
like **ng add @nrwl/angular** or **ng add @nrwl/react**.

Than you can generate the libs using below command.
ng g lib mylib --project=myApp
it will use the respective schematics to generate the lib.